# Typescript import errors

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, npm-install

I am trying to make a simple websockets-based app, where there is a number of components and logic between them, but I'd like to share the state between clients, ie. when one client clicks a button and adds a component, it is added to every client.
I decided to try to do it in Angular+socket.io.
I am stuck at the very beginning, where I took the Angular's [initial app](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local#step-2-create-a-workspace-and-initial-application) and added:

```
import * as socketIo from 'socket.io';
const socket = socketIo('http://localhost:4201');
```

in `main.ts`. I successfully opened this port in a separate "app". When trying to build the Angular part, I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js 113:11-32
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

ERROR in ./node_modules/base64id/lib/base64id.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '..project-path/node_modules/base64id/lib'
...
```

I though this is due to some of the modules not being installed, but:
a) I ran `npm install --save express socket.io @types/express @types/socket.io`, so all the dependencies should be installed I think?
b) I saw some of the missing modules inside `..project-path/node_modules`.

What am I doing wrong? Is it even the problem with npm, Angular or my typescript understanding? How should I handle the dependencies in the future?

Comment: Are you trying to install a server side app in a browser..?

Comment: did you try `import express from "express";`

Comment: I guess this shows some fundamental misunderstanding on my side, but I hoped to have a number of clients whom Angular serves their single-page applications and a communication mechanism implemented via socket.io (added more context to the question). Do I have to have some explicit server on the other side?

Comment: When trying to `import express from "express"` I get `Module '"..project-path/node_modules/@types/express/index"' can only be default-imported using the '
allowSyntheticDefaultImports`